# How to get Business Intelligence Development Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssrs

I need Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) installed on my workstation (Win XP/x86). I don't need the SQL server itself since I will be developing and deploying against another server.

I installed [SQL Server 2005 Express Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B448B0D0-EE79-48F6-B50A-7C4F028C2E3D&displaylang=en) with the reporting services component enabled, but this didn't give me BIDS it appears.

Is there any standalone installation for BIDS or do I have to install the full SQL Server 2005 to get BIDS? I'm pretty sure I've read that SSRS is 'free' since it's included in the express edition, but does this not include the development environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install SQL Server 2005 with client tools without installing the database engine, or other SQL Server services.
Do you have access to a enterprise/standard/development dvd/cd of sql server 2005?

If not the [free/express version of BIDS](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=3C856B93-369F-4C6F-9357-C35384179543&displaylang=en) is available for download from Microsoft.  I do not know if it has a full feature set compared to the full version, anyone care to comment?

Comment: Note that this version has big limitations as it "provides the ability to create and edit Reporting Services projects that are reporting on LOCAL relational data in local SQL Server EXPRESS databases.

Answer (score 1):

When you install SQL Server 2005, it can flake out and not install BIDS if you're not careful.  You need to make sure the part 'Workstation components' (IIRC) is selected for installation.

Answer (score 0):

> > If not the free/express version of BIDS is available for download from Microsoft. I do not know if it has a full feature set compared to the full version, anyone care to comment?

No, this does not have the full feature set compared to the full version.  I'm not sure about the differences on the Reporting Services side, but the ability to use it with Analysis Services is unavailable in the free/express version.

-rp